# TimescaleDB Data Model

Tags: database, postgresql, model, time-series, timescaledb

I'm new to TimescaleDB and I have a question about how to model my data with it and hypertables.
Just to give you a little bit of context, **in the project I'm developing, I have time series data coming from a PLC with several sensors and, besides that, I have to store user information (email, password, etc.)**.

I discover TimescaleDB and I thought it would fit my necessities because it allows me to store the user data and the time series data in the same database.

**However, what I don't understand is this: Should the user data be model as normal PostgreSQL tables and use hypertables only for time-series data? or Should both of them be inside a hypertable?**

**Do you think using TimescaleDB in this case is a good approach?**

Thanks for reading my question!

Comment: You should only use hypertables for time-series data. Whether or not TimescaleDB is a good fit is a matter of opinion, so it's not a very suitable question for this site, and it also depends on things like the scale of your data.

Comment: You can mix hypertables with normal PostgreSQL tables so there is no reason to put the user data in the time series table. If you, for some reason, want to put the user data in the hypertable that is of course possible too.

Comment: If you are going to use TimescaleDB I would look into using node-red. I can post some code if you would like. There a 2 ways of logging structured and unstructured. I prefer structured simply because it's better for end users reporting usage. If your data structure going change often, you want to go with unstructured.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your replies.
Hi CTGControls, I'm currently using node js for this project and I can't change it at this point, but I'll look for node-red info, for future projects, thank you!